# Create dynamic boostrap columns from angularjs variable

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm setting up a web page (I'm a newbie) using php + laravel, blade, bootstrap and angularjs. I want to display columns of images/data, like this:

```
img1    img2    img3    img4
data1   data2   data3   data4

img5    img6    img7    img8
data5   data6   data7   data8
```

These are stored inside an array with hashmaps inside and I can fetch it as an angularjs variable inside the html. I have no problem of making it into a static web page which looks like the above.

My question is: what is the best way to make this dynamic?  I have googled and found several solutions. Either I could use ng-repeat, but the problem is that it seems to be difficult if you want it in multiple bootstrap columns (one is no problem). I DID succeed with that, but I get animation problems (when I hover over one image, all other images are affected my the animation). So that seemed like a bad solution. I could also use a for-loop in blade or in plain php code inside php tags in blade. The two latter options seem more simple, but I can't transform an angularjs variable into a php variable in an easy way so that I can loop through it. It seems to me like a really common thing to do (looping through dynamic data and displaying it nicely in multiple columns), so there must be a simple solution for it.

So what do I do? Should I skip the whole angularjs thing for this purpose? Perhaps it doesn't make sense to use angularjs variables here?

Comment: if you did succeed it only sounds like a bug in your animation script

Comment: The animation script works fine when I make a static web page. It only messes up when I use ng-repeat to make it dynamic.

Comment: but then it might still be different class names.. or other animation relevant changes in the dom?